# RXJS Async Pipe Operator in HTML not triggering complex query

Tags: angular, rxjs

I know that | async inside the HTML triggers a subscribe. Now i have a more complex query which is not submitting. When I assign an observable to my observable field.

ReportsComponent.html:

```
    <mat-form-field *ngIf="initialCheckboxTick" class="col-12">
        <mat-label>Elevations</mat-label>
        <mat-select multiple [(value)]="selectedElevations">
            <mat-optgroup *ngFor="let phase of phasesWithElevations$ | async" [label]="phase.name">
                <mat-option
                        *ngFor="let elevation of phase.elevations"
                        [value]="elevation.id"
                >
                    {{elevation.name}}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-optgroup>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```

ApiService.ts:

```
public getPhases(): Observable<Phase[]> {
    return this._httpClient.get<Phase[]>(this._apiUrl + '/phases').pipe(
        // @ts-ignore
        map(res => res.data),
        tap(
            (phases: Phase[]) => {
                this._phasesSource.next(phases);
            }
        )
    );
}

public getPhasesAndElevations(currentProjectId: string): Observable<Phase[]> {
    return this.getPhases()
        .pipe(
            concatMap(
                phases => of(...phases).pipe(
                    tap(
                        x => console.log('Phase', x)
                    ),
                    concatMap(
                        (phase: Phase) => {
                            return concat(
                                this.selectPhase(phase.id).pipe(
                                    ignoreElements(),
                                ),
                                this.getElevations().pipe(
                                    map(res => {
                                        // @ts-ignore
                                        phase.elevations = res.data;
                                        return phase;
                                    })
                                ),
                                this.selectProject(currentProjectId).pipe(
                                    ignoreElements(),
                                ),
                            );
                        })
                )
            ),
            toArray()
        );
}
```

ReportsComponent.ts:

```
this.phasesWithElevations$: Observable<Phase[]>;

setCategory() {
    this.phasesWithElevations$ = this._apiService.getPhasesAndElevations(this._projectService.project.id);
}
```

I call the `setCategory` method on the first select of an category inside the mat-select.

I would be glad if someone points me to the problem. I think the problems lies inside the complex query.

Stackblitz:
[Found here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-7-rxjs-obs)
Looks like its working inside my stackblitz.

Comment: A running stackblitz would help us a lot. Apart from that are you getting the log in `tap()`?

Comment: what technology are you using to get the data? The http client, or something else? It feels like the inner observables do not complete, which the `toArray()` expects. Also, can you show the `this.getPhases()` implementation?

Comment: Also check the `concat` operator. As `ignoreElements` return Obsevable<never>, which will make the `concat` to not emit values, even if its other sources emits the value. Check [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nskszb?file=index.ts).

Comment: getPhases isnt even triggered so its already stoping there. Added getPhases. The problem is, that those `selects` are returning and empty {} object. I want to skip these objects with ignoreElements()

Comment: Added stackblitz. But created it in an easier kind and mocked the http calls.

Comment: Wouldn't that work ```let phase of (phasesWithElevations$ | async)```

Comment: @maurycy that really was the problem -_-
I used this `*ngFor="let category of categoriesWithReports$ | async"` some lines above, worked without any problem.

Comment: @maurycy would you be so kind an answer the question so i can approve your answer and upvote it?

Comment: `*ngFor="let category of categoriesWithReports$ | async"` should work (as it does in the stackblitz). It's only if you wanted to do `*ngFor="let category of (categoriesWithReports$ | async).memberAccess"` that backets are needed.

Comment: Yeah right, but that wasnt the case on `let phase of (phasesWithElevations$ | async)` neither?

Comment: @AndrewAllen This is a thing that makes me scratch my head. When you pass the expression `let category of categoriesWithReports$` to a pipe, IMHO `(observable$ | async)` has to be resolved first so then you can do `let category of [valueFromSubscription]` hence the brackets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments. There were some missing brackets around the pipe call.

This:

```
*ngFor="let phase of phasesWithElevations$ | async"
```

Should be this:

```
*ngFor="let phase of (phasesWithElevations$ | async)"
```

There is nothing about this necessary brackets inside the documentation [AsyncPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe). Anyway its working inside my stackblitz without brackets. So its really something about the compiler or about the properties I am using afterwards. The IDE I am using is WebStorm.